# php different cpu usage same file?

Tags: php, memory, memory-management, cpu, cpu-usage

I have problem with exceeeding CPU usage by my website on a shared hosting.

I'm just doing a test and it seems that for the same file I can get different CPU values.
I'm testing simple htm with some simple php inserted and mostly I get 0 CPU usage. But somethimes this values raise to 25, 35 or even 85 !

Is it correct to have different CPU usage for the same script?
Is it normal to have as much as 85 or around for a simple script?

Thanks

EDIT: I use a script to check the usage:

```
public static function onRequestStart() {
    $dat = getrusage();
    define('PHP_TUSAGE', microtime(true));
    define('PHP_RUSAGE', $dat["ru_utime.tv_sec"]*1e6+$dat["ru_utime.tv_usec"]);
}

public static function getCpuUsage() {
    $dat = getrusage();
    $dat["ru_utime.tv_usec"] = 
        ($dat["ru_utime.tv_sec"]*1e6 + $dat["ru_utime.tv_usec"]) - PHP_RUSAGE;
    $time = (microtime(true) - PHP_TUSAGE) * 1000000;

    // cpu per request
    if($time > 0) {
        $cpu = sprintf("%01.2f", ($dat["ru_utime.tv_usec"] / $time) * 100);
    } else {
        $cpu = '0.00';
    }

    self::add_session_data($cpu); // this add data to db or display on the screen

    return $cpu;
}
```

onRequestStart() goes into the beggining of the scripts, getCpuUsage() goes at the end

Comment: How are you testing this?

Comment: how are you determining the scripts cpu usage?

Comment: for testing you must stop public service

Comment: Mohammad, do you mean I should stop the website for my users?

Comment: tnx, I put the site on maintenance, but it's still the same: in most cases 0 but sometimes a lot: 34, 58, 73, 124, 42 etc

Comment: your cpu usage is not solely determined by a single process.

Comment: ok, so how should I test it?

Comment: I'm just unable to find where the problem is in my scripts if I can't get a reliable cpu data

Answer (score 0):

If you think your script is slow and you want to know which areas are best for improvements, you should not try to build your own cpu usage meter. Instead you should use a profiler such as [XDebug](http://www.xdebug.org/docs/profiler) or [XHProf](http://pecl.php.net/package/xhprof). They will be able to tell you which functions and methods take long to run. Those are the things you should focus on.

Comment: Thanks but I use shared hosting, I can't install any of the software you advised. I could on my local machine but I use Mac and they are all for Windows/Linux.

Comment: Both also work on Mac. You could use `homebrew` or `macports` to install things, or just google for installation instructions.